# MS Chart remove space between Series

Tags: vb.net, charts, mschart, series

I recently created a 3D View with the StackedColumnChart in VB.NET But now I don't know how to remove the Space between two series.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved it myself.
For anyone who wants to know:
Chart1.ChartAreas("A").Area3DStyle.PointGapDepth = 0